# Go back to original app after opening another app through an intent

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I have an android app in which I open an email app like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + EMAIL_PROTECTORA)); 
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Adopt");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mPetDetails);

                    Uri pictureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mPhotoUri));
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pictureUri);

                    if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
```

It works fine, but after the email has been sent I want to go back to my app again, and with this when I hit back I can only navigate through the email app without reaching my original app again. Is there any way to fix that? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't control the behaviour of another app. What you are describing is a mistake in the email app, not yours. Don't worry about it. You can't fix the mistakes the developers of the other app make. It should work like you want it work, but the developers of the email for some reason specifically implemented the wrong behaviour (most likely without knowing it).

Comment: Which email app are you talking about?

Comment: And by the way you should eventually, if you hit the back button often enough, reach your app again. The email app just opens a whole activity stack instead of just the activity which sends the email.

Comment: Actually is gmail. When I hit back repeatedly I end up in the phone menu, the only way I have of going back to my app is opening the recent activities tab and selecting again the app from there. Is kind of annoying